# Angular como recargar pagina automaticamente despues de borrar un elemento de una listay que se vea reflejado la actualizacion del usuario borrado

Tags: angular, angular5

Quiero que despues del **alert** que dice que el usuario ha sido borrado que reinicie el componente, pero que no cargue toda la pagina

**Funcion que borrar el usuario seleccionado**

```
  borrar(id:string){

    var confirmacion = confirm("Estas seguro que quieres borrar el usuario con ID = "+id);
    if (confirmacion) {
      let user_para_borrar = new Usuario(id,'','','','',new Date());
      this.usuarioService.delete(user_para_borrar).subscribe(
        usuario=>{
          if (usuario) {
            alert('El Usuario se ha borrado correctamente');

          }
        },
        error=>{
          alert('Error al borrar personaje')
        }
      )
    }

  }
```

Comment: Podrias reformular tu pregunta no se entiende, puedes agregar una imagen del valor antes de eliminar y platicar la accion despues de eliminarlo.

Answer (score 1):

debes de tener un `form` en el `ngOnInit`, o declarado en un método el cual inicializas en el `ngOnInit` de esta forma:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.tuFormulario = new FormGroup({
      nameInput: nameInput,
    });
 }
```

este `form` contiene el campo o los campos del formulario, puedes hacer un `reset()` al `form` para que limpies sin cargar la pagina asi.

```
this.tuformulario.reset();
```

esto limpia el formulario sin recargar la pagina.

Debes tener en cuenta que si estas eliminado registros de una tabla debes de volver a cargar la información de la base de datos.

**Al momento de mostrar el alerte cargar de nuevo los usuarios para que se vea reflejado que si se elimino el usuario**

Comment: Como cargas el formulario? con el objeto traido de la bd? si es asi, deberias reiniciar el objeto
var objetoSeleccionado={};
Eso hace que el objeto se vacie y el formulario tambien se vacia.. ya que esta asociado a ese objeto...

Comment: @Cribelo, si lees la respuesta te darás cuenta que lo que comentas ya lo había puesto. **"Debes tener en cuenta que si estas eliminado registros de una tabla debes de volver a cargar la información de la base de datos."**